# How can I pick out some commit in my git branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have many commits in my branch but some commit it's not necessary and that makes my team confused. So in these cases, 6 commits in develop origin branch.

1--2--3--4--5--6
I want to remove all change and commit in 3 and 4 and the commit should be 1--2--5--6 but I don't know how to fix it with Git CLI.

thank you for help me solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this branch is already being shared by your entire team, the safe thing to do here is to just `git revert` the 3 and 4 commits:

```
git revert -n 3^..4
git commit -m 'added revert commit for 3 and 4'
```

Replace `3` and `4` above with the SHA-1 hashes of these commits.  You may find the SHA-1 hashses by typing `git log` from your Git bash.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for so fast response, Tim. I'll make sure of my understanding.

commit :

```
1 - 5d67c8f001
2 - 5d67c8f002
3 - 5d67c8f003
4 - 5d67c8f004
5 - 5d67c8f005
6 - 5d67c8f006

git revert -n 5d67c8f003^..5d67c8f004
git commit -m 'added revert commit for 3 and 4'
```

it's right?